# Properly setting mathrel on negated symbol with \NewNegationCommand

Tags: fontspec, unicode-math

The default definition of `\not\models` is not satisfying regarding spacing :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
$a\models b$

$a\not\models b$
\end{document}
```

gives

[image: default spacing]

I think it is because it is lacking a `\mathrel` : adding it manually gives a correct spacing. Of course typing this each time is not acceptable so I am trying to define a `\notmodels` to do this.

I found that unicode-math does some changes to the old `\not` and provides a `\NewNegationCommand`.

However, the maybe naive

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\NewNegationCommand\models{\mathrel{\not\models}}
\begin{document}
$a\models b$

$a\notmodels b$
\end{document}
```

gives : *TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [semantic nest size=500]. $a\notmodels*

Suspecting an endless recursion, I tried

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\edef\ysnm{\not\models}
\NewNegationCommand\models{\mathrel{\ysnm}}
\begin{document}
$a\models b$

$a\notmodels b$
\end{document}
```

but it gives : *Missing { inserted. $a\notmodels*, which I find quite disturbing.

Third attempt

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\AtBeginDocument{
\newbox\boxnm
\setbox\boxnm=\hbox{$\not\models$}
\NewNegationCommand\models{\mathrel{\copy\boxnm}}
}
\begin{document}
$a\models b$

$a\notmodels b$
\end{document}
```

works…

But I find this very puzzling.

How can I get out of this in a better way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Negating symbols is a pain with `unicode-math`. `:-(` But there's a way out. `:-)`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\Umathchardef\altnot=3 \symsymbols "0338

\NewNegationCommand{\models}{\models\mathrel{\mkern1mu}\altnot\mkern-1mu}

\begin{document}

$a\models b$

$a\not\models b$

$a\notmodels b$

\end{document}
```

The syntax for `\NewNegatedCommand` is

```
\NewNegatedCommand{\foo}{<code>}
```

where `\foo` is the relation symbol to be negated. This defines both the combination `\not\foo` and the command `\notfoo`.

Here I use a small kern in order to avoid the clash.

[image]

By the way, this seems to be a bug in XeTeX for `\mathoverlayaccent`, because the combination `\not\models` works in LuaLaTeX (albeit giving wrong spacing), which could be cured with

```
\NewNegationCommand{\models}{\mathrel{\notaccent\models}}
```

but the output is not as satisfying

[image]

The solution with `\altnot` works with both XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX.

Comment: Actually, the second solution looks better with my fonts. BTW, \kern{-1mu} causes a compilation error on my system (lualatex) ; removing the curly braces works.

Comment: I think the point about \notaccent should get more emphasis, because this is what I had in mind : how to do the "default not", but with a correct \mathrel. BTW, why the default \not\models does not set space properly is strange to me : a negated symbol is of the same "class" as the base symbol.

Comment: @ysalmon I've fixed it in answer, by replacing `\mkern{-1mu}` with `\mkern-1mu`.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ Thanks, I apparently got confused with `\mspace`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't ask why but the following works (which basically does one expansion manually):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\NewNegationCommand{\models}{\mathrel{\not⊧}}
\begin{document}
$a\models b$

$a\notmodels b$
\end{document}
```

Comment: This does not produce errors, but no good output either.

Comment: More precisely: the output is bad with XeLaTeX, better with LuaLaTeX.

Comment: @egreg That's what the manual mentions concerning `\NewNegationCommand` (better support in LuaLaTeX than Xe)…