# Negating a user-defined relation with XeLaTeX

Tags: math-mode, unicode-math

The following works OK with pdfLaTeX.

But with XeLaTeX, `$ x \notrelR y$` gives a "Missing number, treated as zero" error.

I'm using the method shown in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/475345/13492.

What's wrong?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\relR}{\mathrel{R}}

\usepackage{iftex}
\ifTUTeX
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}[Scale=1.0]
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
  \Umathchardef\altnot=3 \symsymbols "0338
  \NewNegationCommand{\relR}{\relR\mathrel{\mkern1mu}\altnot\mkern{-1mu}}
\else
  \newcommand{\notrelR}{\not\relR}
\fi

\begin{document}

$x \relR y$

$ x \notrelR y$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Replace `\mkern{-1mu}` by `\mkern-1mu`, because `\mkern` never supports syntax `\mkern{<dimen>}`. It is a typo from the linked answer, and I've fixed it there.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ: OK, that does not give error -- but the negation sign is badly misplaced to the left of the R then!

Answer (score 1):

1. Replace `\mkern{-1mu}` with `\mkern-1mu`, as stated in question comment.
2. Adjust value of first `\mkern`, which is `1mu`, to fit the width of `R` in current math font. I use `-1mu` in the following example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\relR}{\mathrel{R}}

\usepackage{iftex}
\ifTUTeX
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}[Scale=1.0]
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
  \Umathchardef\altnot=3 \symsymbols "0338
  \NewNegationCommand{\relR}{\relR\mathrel{\mkern-1mu}\altnot\mkern-1mu}
\else
  \newcommand{\notrelR}{\not\relR}
\fi

\begin{document}

$x \relR y$

$ x \notrelR y$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: OK, that works for the particular relation `\relR`. But I think the method using a defined `\overlaynot` as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/545301/13492, which I just found,  works more reliably for various relations.

Comment: @murray Yes, it is. `\overlaynot` measures the width of relation symbol, so works better.